# Qt - Why add '&' to the string?

Tags: c++, qt

```
QPushButton *quitButton = new QPushButton("&Quit");
```

Why add a `&` to the `Quit`? Removing `&` and it seems the code behaves the same.

Comment: Try to press Alt and after that Q and you will see what & means.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The *ampersand* makes the button respond to a particular key-combination. In your case, if you press **ALT** + **Q** it will force the button to be pushed.

From [Qt](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpushbutton.html)

The QPushButton widget provides a command button.

The push button, or command button, is perhaps the most commonly used widget in any graphical user interface. Push (click) a button to command the computer to perform some action, or to answer a question. Typical buttons are OK, Apply, Cancel, Close, Yes, No and Help.

A command button is rectangular and typically displays a text label describing its action. A shortcut key can be specified by preceding the preferred character with an ampersand in the text. For example:

```
 QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("&Download", this);
```

In this example the shortcut is Alt+D. See the QShortcut documentation for details (to display an actual ampersand, use '&&').

Comment: I'd also add that this is commonly referred to as "mnemonic".

Answer (score 5):

The ampersand means that the letter 'Q' next to it will be used as a keyboard shortcut.