# Qt Designer add '&' (ampersand) in text automatically

Tags: qt, qt5

I am using Qt 5.11.1 on Manjaro Linux.
When I open Qt Designer, create a new dialog and add stuff on the widget, Qt Designer adds '&' (ampersand)  in the text in some types of widgets automatically. (Ampersand "&" is shortcut in Qt, commonly referred to as "mnemonic". For example, if text of button is "b&utton", I can click the button with `Alt + U`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16666135/3926429) for more information.) For example, if I create a radio button and set the text to "button", the text will become "b&utton" automatically, and I cannot remove the '&'. What should I do?

Comment: Do nothing? What is the actual problem? Is & visible on running GUI?

Comment: & is shortcut in Qt. For example, if the text is "b&utton", the 'u' is shown with underscore and '&' is not shown. But I don't want it.

Comment: The properties don't have shortcut definition? Sounds like there could be some "auto" setting as  default.

Comment: looks like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32688153/how-to-disable-automatic-mnemonics-in-a-qt-application-on-kde

Comment: Why my question is downvoted? Can someone tell me how to improve my question?

Comment: I edited my question. Maybe this is better now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaroud in [How to disable automatic mnemonics in a Qt application on KDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32688153/how-to-disable-automatic-mnemonics-in-a-qt-application-on-kde) works. Thank you Andrii for providing the link!
The workaroud is to add

```
[Development]
AutoCheckAccelerators=false
```

to `~/.config/kdeglobals`.

I also found that removing the package `kdelibs4support` is also a workaround, but some packages might depend on it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, probably [qt_set_sequence_auto_mnemonic](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequence.html#qt_set_sequence_auto_mnemonic) function is what you are looking for.

> Specifies whether mnemonics for menu items, labels, etc., should be honored or not. On Windows and X11, this feature is on by default; on macOS, it is off. When this feature is off (that is, when b is false), QKeySequence::mnemonic() always returns an empty string.
>
> Note: This function is not declared in any of Qt's header files. To use it in your application, declare the function prototype before calling it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to use it. But the workaround in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32688153/how-to-disable-automatic-mnemonics-in-a-qt-application-on-kde works. Thank you very much for providing the link!