# PyQt5 - In QAction() and menuBar.addMenu() methods whats is the '&' standing for?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm learning PyQt5 at the moment and now I'm studying the QAction method in order to perform and action from the menu of my application

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QAction, qApp, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

def initUI(self):
    exitAct = QAction(QIcon('exit.png'), '&Exit', self)
    exitAct.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
    exitAct.setStatusTip("Exit application")
    exitAct.triggered.connect(qApp.exit)

    self.statusBar()

    menubar = self.menuBar()
    fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
    fileMenu.addAction(exitAct)
    self.setGeometry(300,300,300,200)
    self.setWindowTitle('Simple Menu')
    self.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What I'm wondering in QAction function and addMenu(), what is the '&' in '&Exit' and '&File' standing for ? Or at least are they necessary to be kept ? Even though I deleted them it didn't change anything to their appearance or to the action they were meant to perform

Because I see it very often in scripts written by other programmers am I missing something ?

Comment: It makes the following letter the [mnemonic/accelerator key](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qshortcut.html#details), which is usually indicated by an underline (depending on the platform).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt - Why add '&' to the string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666060/qt-why-add-to-the-string)

Comment: Thank you very much ! yes it's the same problem in a different language